# The greeting from an IMAP server — format?

Tags: email, imap, protocols

I'm trying to understand the specification of IMAP found at
[INTERNET MESSAGE ACCESS PROTOCOL - VERSION 4rev1 (RFC3501)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501)
Does the greeting from a server always have the following format?

```
* OK something doesn't matter what
```

That is, does it start with `* OK` **always** and has the * and one whitespace in the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

No. It can have at least three variants (see page 14):

```
     (1) connection without pre-authentication (OK greeting)
     (2) pre-authenticated connection (PREAUTH greeting)
     (3) rejected connection (BYE greeting)
```

Comment: is "pre-authentication" different from the main authentication process by login and password? With pre-authentication, are there 2 steps?

Comment: Preauth is mainly a debugging tool. http://wiki.dovecot.org/PreAuth

Comment: so there the 1st character or word in greeting isn't * ?

Comment: so the 1st character or word in greeting isn't * ?

Comment: Read chapter 2.2, it makes it clear the server can only respond with `*` on the beginning of the line for the greeting,  as it is neither continuing a data stream (`+`) nor responding to a tagged command (where it would respond with the tag send by the client). As far as RFCs go, this section is quite easy to understand ...

Comment: then I'll keep asking you because for you it's easy to understand.